# Should I use one SQLiteHelper for all SQLiteDatabases in my app or one for each one of them?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Well, the title says it all. I'm new to usage of SQL in Android development, so I would appreciate an advice.

Comment: You should have one [SQLite-Open-Helper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) class per database: "A helper class to manage [*a*] database creation and version management."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have one `SQLiteOpenHelper` for each different database file your app will have. I recommend that for any particular database, you use a single instance of the corresponding `SQLiteOpenHelper` class to access it, even if multiple threads want to access that database.